# Cassandra/DataStax client is not returning UDT object from the keyspace

Tags: cassandra, datastax

I have created UDT in Cassandra 
Employee UDT
[image: Employee UDT]

Corresponding c# class as below:

```
public class Employee
{
    public int emp_id { get; set; }
    public string emp_name { get; set; }
    public int emp_age { get; set; }

}
```

And following code to connect and map UDT with corresponding c# class:

```
 var cluster = Cluster.Builder()
            .AddContactPoint("localhost")
            .Build();
        ISession session = cluster.Connect("firstkeyspace");

        //session.UserDefinedTypes.Define(UdtMap.For<Employee>().Automap());

        session.UserDefinedTypes.Define(UdtMap.For<Employee>("employee", keyspace: "firstkeyspace"));


        var rs = session.Execute("select * from employee");
```

At retrieval using following code line:

```
 Employee employee = row.GetValue<Employee>("employee");
```

I'm getting the following error:

[image: error]

Please take a look and let me know if anything missing.

Answer (score 0):

The error is correct your table definition doesn't have a column with name `employee` with type `employee`.  Modify your table definition to include corresponding column.

Update, based on discussion: What you really need is the [object mapper](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/csharp-driver/3.14/features/components/mapper/) that is available as part of C# driver.

User defined types is just a way for grouping things together to represent them as one column inside the table. For example, you can represent address as UDT with fields street, ctity, post code, state, country, and put this UDT as one column in your table. Or you can put all this information as separate columns into a table. But if you have multiple tables using the same information, then it's easier to use UDT, and have one column per table...

Comment: Why i should specify employee as a column when it's a  UDT or table?  My UDT has only three columns which are emp_id, emp_age and emp_name. It doesn't look appropriate to include employee column which i don't really have.

Comment: But you are trying to fetch column with name employee from a row, and your table doesn’t have it...

Comment: I am trying to fetch the whole data row not a specific column. I believe that's the whole purpose of creating user defined type and mapping it the corresponding class so that we can retrieve the whole record not column.

Comment: No - user defined types is just a way for grouping things together to represent them as one column inside the table. For example, you can represent address as UDT with fields street, ctity, post code, state, country, and put this UDT as one column in your table. Or you can put all this information as separate columns into a table. But if you have multiple tables using the same information, then it's easier to use UDT, and have one column per table...

Comment: you really need Object Mapper for your language - I've updated the answer